# SQL Search timeout issue with two character search

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]When I run this query it is taking two much of time, approx 3 minutes. Freetext search is enabled on the table
SQL Server 2008 R2. Table contains record : 3000000 and with catalogueid :57777 contains 64 Rows

Query 1 :

```
select COUNT(1) from CatalogueItemSearch  where CatalogueID=57777 and CONTAINS(SearchData,'"CID57777CID AND NN*"')
```

And when I just add triple NNN* it gives output in second.

Query 2 :

```
select COUNT(1) from CatalogueItemSearch  where CatalogueID=57777 and CONTAINS(SearchData,'"CID57777CID AND NNN*"')
```

Can you tell me why SQL is not giving output instantaneous with two character. While more than two character search it is giving output in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the test index is not being used due to high cardinality estimation.
Please verify by checking the execution plan.